# C++ push front iteration

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration

I've got a Tab class which has a list of Components.

```
list<Component*> Tab::getComponents() {
    return (this->components);
}

void Tab::addComponent(Component* comp){
    this->components.push_front(comp);
}

Tab::Tab() {
    // x = 25, y = 30
Button* one = new Button(25,30,300,100, "images/button.png");
this->addComponent(one);

Button* two = new Button(75,100,300,100, "images/button.png");
this->addComponent(two);

    // x = 150, y = 150
Button* three = new Button(150,150,300,100, "images/button.png");
this->addComponent(three);  
}
```

Now for the problematic code:

```
list<Component*>::iterator it = activeTab->getComponents().begin(); 
for (it ; it != activeTab->getComponents().end(); it++) {
    offset.x = (*it)->getX();
    cout << "offset.x = " << offset.x << endl;
    offset.y = (*it)->getY();
    cout << "offset.y = " << offset.y << endl;
}
```

This is the output of the first iteration of the `for` loop:

```
offset.x = 25
offset.y = 30
```

But, seeing that I used `push_front()`, it should be:

```
offset.x = 150
offset.y = 150
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: the second iteration of the `for` loop prints garbage...

```
offset.x = 16272
offset.y = 17
```

And the third just prints `segmentation fault` :(

Comment: The code you've given doesn't print anything out.  Can you post a full example that prints out offset.x and offset.y?  I'm guessing your problem is in that piece of the code, since what you've posted looks reasonable.

Comment: I see an extra `)` in the first line of `for` loop.

Comment: @abhinole, that was a typo :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Tab::getComponents()` returns `list<Component*>` instead of `list<Component*>&`, which means, `this->components` is copied when returning. Thus, let's look at the code:

```
list<Component*>::iterator it = activeTab->getComponents().begin(); 
// ``it'' is already INVALID here since the list returned in the above line
// is already destructed!
for (it ; it != activeTab->getComponents().end(); it++) {
    offset.x = (*it)->getX(); //``it'' is invalid
    cout << "offset.x = " << offset.x << endl;
    offset.y = (*it)->getY();
    cout << "offset.y = " << offset.y << endl;
}
```

The iterator `it` is invalid when you dereference it.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that your method getComponents() is returning a copy, you should return a reference.

```
list<Component*>& Tab::getComponents() {
    return (this->components);
}
```

Comment: Oh, good catch, that's the bug.  In fact I'm surprised the loop terminates at all.

Comment: @Soverman It doesn't, it segfaults. But this certainly explains the segfault.